# Add custom propertysource to standardservletenvironment

Tags: spring

I have a Spring 4 application as a classic Tomcat WAR deployment, and I want to add a custom PropertySource to the Enviroment. The Spring 4 docs state it should be as simple as saying

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
MutablePropertySources sources = ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
sources.addFirst(new MyPropertySource());
```

So, as soon as my AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext is instantiated, I added lines 2 and 3 from the sample above. However, further in the boot process, a GenericFilterBean (subclass) is instantiated that simple does:

```
private Environment environment = new StandardServletEnvironment();
```

From this point on, my CustomPropertySource is gone, and of course, properties won't get loaded the right way. When I debug the PropertySourcePlaceHolderConfigurer, the environment use there is the one instantiated by the GenericFilterBean.

Has anyone got this to work with a custom PropertySource?

Comment: You need an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to register your custom property source.

Comment: Thanx, this works by implementing getServletApplicationContextInitializers from AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer